# Geometry on manifolds - Adapted coordinate chart for a curve

Tags: smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $\gamma:I\to M$ a smooth curve on $M$. How can I construct a local chart $(U,\psi)$ such that $U\cap \gamma(I)\ne \emptyset$ and $\gamma(t)\equiv(\gamma^1(t),0,\ldots,0)$ for all $t$?

Comment: Do you have to construct a local chart for each point in $\gamma(I)$?

Comment: Where $\gamma'(t)\ne 0$, use the [constant rank theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem). At points where $\gamma'(t)=0$, you can't.